# Android Google Maps Api v2 onInfoWindowClick freezes and crashes trying to open new Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm desperate because when I try to open a new Activity after clicking on a marker info window, the program freezes and crashes.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  (..........)

map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        Intent x = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
            x.putExtra(Name, Info);
            startActivity(x); 
           }
    });}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: You will have to excuse me, I found the "stupid" error: The Second.class wasn`t in the AndroidManifest.xml, sorry.